# RF high power amp bias scheme

Tags: rf, current-measurement, power-amplifier

I am using the TGA2237-SM for the TX side in a front end design. I am trying to figure out an analog method for doing the bias up and bias down procedures.

Bias up

1. Set gate to Vg=-5V
2. Increase Vg till Id=360mA (drain current), Vg~-2.6V
3. Apply RF

Bias down

1. Turn off RF
2. Decrease Vg to -5V
3. Turn off supplies

I was thinking of using a current sense amplifier similar to the LT6106, where my load would be the drain of my RF amp and the Vout of the LT6106 would be the gate of the RF amp. See image below.

[image]

I need the Vout to start at a voltage and then increase based on the load current increase. This sort of analog design is not my wheelhouse, but I feel like this should be easy, but something is eluding me.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  One thing I can confirm reading your goal and the circuit proposed is that this configuration exhibit a positive feedback. The more current your RF draw the more bias your RF stage will receive, making it increase until saturation and possibly catastrophic consequences.  You need to reverse the input polarity such that when RF current increase the bias go low. the rest consist in balancing the (then negative) feedback loop such that it feed your desired values.

Comment: Please mention the period required for your circuit to go through the Bias-Up and Bias-Down procedure. You need milliseconds or second order of magnitude ?

Comment: Hello Fred, thank you very much for responding and I apologize for any lack of clarity. I need the bias procedure to happen as fast as possible (sorry for being vague). I was going to use some uC GPIO pins to adjust this bias, but I thought that I could probably do this in some analog fashion. My front end is going to RX for 99% of the time and TX just needs to turn on, transmit, and turn off. I was originally just going to set the gate to -5, turn on the bias supply, and have a GPIO set the gate directly to -2.6, but I thought that I should maybe monitor that drain current.

Comment: Sure, drain current monitoring is certainly a good approach. Please tell how your control circuit will know when its time to transmit and receive. I certainly am able to come up with a simple solution for you.

Comment: When it is time to TX or RX, I have a single CMOS signal being split, where one trace goes through a buffer and one through an inverter, and those signals are then feeding a load switch. the load switch is taking 5V from a power section and using that to power the RX and TX side.

Comment: I already have all the DC conversion and CMOS signal stuff figured out, it is just this bias procedure. I could probably get away with just going from -5 to -2.6 on the gate, but that is probably the quick and dirty way.

Comment: My circuit will utilize your 5V inverted signal to commute the Vg. Hold on Im working on it.  :)

Comment: ON page 12 of the datasheet it is shown 2 capacitors C1 C2 and resistors R1 R2 going somewhere. What are these channels for ?  Is VG a major source of RF ? Should VG be insulated from a control signal ? I am concerned with the fact that a control source of low impedance on VG may disturb the RF input signal. Have you got  some practical experience with this chip already ? Your thoughts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proposed solution. Please revise and let me know if you have any concerns or point to details I may have forgotten.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Fred, I will analyze this and comment again. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: One factor that came to mind after a nigh of sleep: that circuit maintain a tight control on current consumption. If the input RF signal is AM, the circuit is fast enough to lower the bias as fast as some milliseconds, which can seriously impede in the quality of transmitted signal.  Perhaps the reaction time should be slowed down to a period higher than the lowest transmitted input signal modulation period. IE: if you are transmitting an AM signal modulated with a frequency in the order of 20 hertz the circuit, as it is, will prevent such slow modulation. Your thoughts...

Comment: I think perhaps that I was overthinking this. The Vg will not have any RF, so I am thinking I should just have Vg always sitting at -5V. My control signal will turn on 32V rail. That same control signal will be applied to an opamp voltage divider buffer that I can tune with potentiometer. The current consumption when the amp Vg is sitting at -5V should be minimal. This is for more R&D, so max power effiiciency is not required at this point.

Comment: My board takes in +5V for power, which powers all RX components. That same +5V goes through a boost converter for the +32V, as well as a charge pump converter for the -5V for Vg. The PA is the only component that requries the +32V and the -5V. Vg always sitting at -5V, control signal enables the +32V boost, and also enables the voltage division of -5V to ~2.6V. I was originally thinking that I should dynamically divide this voltage, but actually, I should only have to do this one time to make sure I get the correct drain current.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but from the datasheet it is my understanding that IDQ is controlled by IG. If you set VG permanently to -5V how are you going to get some current consumption from IDQ ? another question: Does the TGA2237 draw current based on the RF input signal strength even when VG is down to -5V ? ( see page 12 "Bias Up Prodecure)

Comment: Would you prefer an arrangement where you manually set VG with a trim pot and the actual VG=-2.6V would remain like that despite IDQ varying while RF modulation takes place ?  In such case you may not even need to bother with an LT6106, you just set VG with the help of a multi-meter and that is it.

Comment: yeah, I think the pot could set that voltage one time with the mulitmeter as you say. I would not anticipate that IDQ would vary each time TX is turned on.

Comment: RF should not be applied while Vg is at -5V. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: According to TGA2237 ddatasheet page 12 Bias Procedure, it is mentionned at step 4 "Adjust VG more positive until IDQ = 360 mA (VG ~ -2.6 V Typical) "

Comment: Would pulling current to GND with a resistor be adequate enough for VG regulation or would it be needed an OpAmp that would insure exact VG voltage ?

Comment: Here is a link to another arrangement:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/12CM3dxoe-U2uPL5QdR8wf22q9krqnKP-/view?usp=sharing    Let me know

Comment: Here is a link for a third solution    https://drive.google.com/file/d/14hj0WfyrjtqKglvezONx36cfqIHBLfV8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: New link to third solution revised for Pi4       https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xYoN4fCzUmaRi8pldb13vEpA7ouU6bLM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Fred, I was thinking of something like this. Not perfect, but very simple. I think my issue might be the R1 resistor. The R1 is the gate, so I guess I could assume High Z. The node between R2 and R3 would have the pot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That could be another approach but why the Opto-Coupler ?  I think the third solution with the OpAmp is simpler to implement and will assure you of an exact -2.6V on VG anytime you trigger the Transmit status.  See link above. Let me know if you have concerns about the realisation. Don't let yourself be scared with a couple of transistors. If you are ready to go with an OpAmp, I think that is the best solution.

Comment: Third schematic with the OpAmp error. R16 should be 47 ohms,  not 4.3k.

Comment: Is it possible to get access to -6Volt instead of -5V ?  ( for the OpAmp)

Comment: Revised OpAmp Solution     https://drive.google.com/file/d/19MS-GSpLOc493uflUg91MosatozpxqvA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see I forgot to mention something. Perhaps I was being too loose by saying CMOS. My control signal is from a pi GPIO 0-3.3. This is why I was using the opto switch to switch between the -5V and the pot. I suppose I could just use a transistor. Question, are you using the -6 because you are concerned with the rail to rail abilities of the op amp? I could make that negative supply whatever I want. I am currently using a charge pump converter, but I could probably just using an inverting op amp configuration. Also, why don't you put your postive supply to your Op amp at GND, why put it at +5V?

Comment: Once again, thank you very much for helping with this.

Comment: Yes -6V would compensate for the OpAmp perhaps not being able of outputting -5V to ensure VG at -5V. If you can feed it with -6V its safer.   The +5V for OpAmp is again a question of having plenty of room for the output to never go in saturation. So little power is involved here that -6V to +5V is no issue for most OpAmp.  The 2N3906 act as an ON/OFF switch from Open to GND (or near) which contribute to a stable repetitive pot output from -2.6 to -5.x (OpAmp dependent) . The 47 ohms R16 and both 10nF caps prevent some RF signal to interfere with the OpAmp DC operation.

Comment: Furthermore, I am concerned about your GPIO as low as 3.3V  .    I will revise my circuit to be compatible with such low voltage. Hang On a few minites.

Comment: New link to third solution - Pi4 version               https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xYoN4fCzUmaRi8pldb13vEpA7ouU6bLM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry... The Trim-pot should read TRIM1 not TRIM2

Comment: Fred, just wanted to send a quick thank you for talking me through this.

Comment: Frank, my pleasure. I enjoyed every minutes. That "thank you" is my pay check :)